# How to open the console during Windows 7 install?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, console, setup

During the Windows 7 install, there is a key combination you can press to get a console prompt. What is that key combination? I just can't remember and I just can't find it on Google or anything...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try Shift + F10.  It worked in Vista, I'm pretty sure it still works in Windows 7.

Comment: Sounds familiar. Will try it out tomorrow :)

Comment: Totally worked! Thanks, and sorry about the late feedback. I've been moving, hehe.